# Django REST Framework full serialization for personal data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What is the proper way to let authenticated users access their own private information, while other users would only be able to access the public information ?

I tried creating 2 serializers:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import User


class PublicUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.ImageField(use_url=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'image_url',
        )
        lookup_field = 'pk'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'pk'}
        }


class PrivateUserSerializer(PublicUserSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'image_url',
            'details',
            'email',
        )
```

But now, I'm wondering how should I update the viewset to choose the proper serializer.

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from app.authentication import FirebaseAuthentication
from app.models import User
from app.serializers import PublicUserSerializer, PrivateUserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)
```

I can override the [get_serializer](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a251b9379200420062cad9e3c68fde7c0e6b3fdc/rest_framework/generics.py#L105) or [get_serializer_class](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a251b9379200420062cad9e3c68fde7c0e6b3fdc/rest_framework/generics.py#L114), but how can I access my user and check permissions within this method ?

**Solution:**

Serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.ImageField(use_url=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'image_url',
            'details',
        ]
        lookup_field = 'pk'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'pk'}
        }


class PrivateUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserSerializer.Meta.fields + [
            'email',
        ]
```

Viewset:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from app.authentication import FirebaseAuthentication
from app.models import User
from app.serializers import UserSerializer, PrivateUserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        if self.request.user == user:
            serializer = PrivateUserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this would do the whole magic :)

```
 class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user:  # If the user authenticated
            return User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id)
        return User.objects.all()  # user not authenticated

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user:  # If the user authenticated
            return PrivateUserSerializer
        else:  # user not authenticated
            return PublicUserSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user:
            private_data = PrivateUserSerializer(User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id),many=True).data
            public_data = PublicUserSerializer(User.objects.exclude(pk=self.request.user.id),many=True).data
            return Response(data=private_data+public_data)
        return Response(data=PublicUserSerializer(User.objects.all(),many=True).data)
```

### UPDATE

The suggested answer by `Fandekasp` is,

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        if self.request.user == user:
            serializer = PrivateUserSerializer(user)
        else:
            serializer = PublicUserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this ! Unfortunately, this won't do it.
We probably don't need to modify get_queryset. Since it's a viewset, I'm assuming it'll adjust the queryset automatically on detail queries.

For the get_serializer_class, there are 2 problems:

* Any authenticated users will be able to see any user private info (should be only his own data)
* self.request.user is Anonymous at this stage. I use a custom FirebaseAuthentication authenticator to return the current user depending on his firebase uid, and it looks like authentication hasn't run yet at that time.

Comment: I didn't get the thing *We probably don't need to modify get_queryset*, Can you explain it little more?

Comment: You said, *Any authenticated users will be able to see any user private info*, this won't happen. Because, If the user is authenticated, then `get_serializer_class` return `PrivateUserSerializer` and `get_queryset` return `User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id)`. Hence the output response will be contain **only his informations serialized with PrivateUserSerializer** class

Comment: oh right, but then an authenticated user would not be able to see any other user public information because his own data would show up instead ? Anyways, since self.request.user is always anonymous at this stage ...

Comment: Oh, my bad !!! The token I was using for this test was expired, which is why it returned anonymous. I updated the token and I can indeed see my user as self.request.user :D

Comment: Yeah.. That's true.  Is this for your `list api` ? right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173937/discussion-between-fandekasp-and-jerin-peter-george).

Answer (score 1):

You'd use Django Rest Framework's permissions

```
# Add this
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

# Your other imports
from rest_framework import viewsets
from app.authentication import FirebaseAuthentication
from app.models import User
from app.serializers import PublicUserSerializer, PrivateUserSerializer


@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
class AllUsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)
    # Apply whatever filters, permissions or logic specific for this level        


@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,])
class AuthenticatedUsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)
    # Apply whatever filters, permissions or logic specific for this level
```

Once you have your viewsets separated, you can adjust their logic.

Comment: If you're asking me to register another viewset to the router, hence create a whole set of new urls, this is no good.

Comment: You can wrap this selection between `AllowAny` and `IsAuthenticated` in a decorator with a parameter - then you're left with one viewset.

Comment: Let me try this again. But I'm afraid this'll allow any authenticated user to see other users private data (when I only want the current user to access his own private info)

Comment: You can do an `if` `else` within decorator based on the incoming parameter - something like  `@select_permissions(user=user)`

Comment: and then within the decorator `if user.is_authenticated():`